# React Checkbox not getting value onCheck

Tags: reactjs, events, checkbox

React Checkbox not getting value onCheck . I tried an accepted answer, and get constant value first , but it is getting undefined(data variable)

```
<TableCell>
    <Checkbox name="myCheckBox1" onChange={(e, data) => this.checkchange1('2', data.value)}/>
</TableCell>


checkchange1 = (e, data) => {
        console.log('it works');
        console.log(data.value);
    }
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: in checkchange1, `data.value` returns `undefined`? If yes, calling `this.checkchange1('2', data)` should console data.value in checkchange1 function. Check

Comment: If `data.value` does not exist. We can pick value from `e` as well in checkchange1 by `e.target.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of checkbox, Try like below

```
<Checkbox name="myCheckBox1" value="checkedA" onChange={(e) => this.checkchange1(e)}/>
```

```
checkchange1 = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value); /* checkedA will be consoled here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onChange will take only one param and that is e.

you can store the value in state like this.

```
<Checkbox onChange={this.toggle} checked={this.state.checked} /> 

 toggle = () => this.setState(({checked}) => ({ checked: !checked }))
```